# Form spacing issue with jquery Validate and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

**EDIT**: See below - this was apparently caused by some sort of browser bug.

---

I've made a form using `Bootstrap`, and I'm validating the data on it using `jqueryval`. The validation itself is all working, but I have a layout problem I can't seem to get to the bottom of.

Here is how it looks at the moment:

[image: Bootstrap and jqueryval - Spacing Issues]

As you can see, when you fill in a field, the status message label is created and added below each textbox. However, when you get it correct, despite being hidden from view, it still takes up the space, as shown with the extra gap beneath the first one.

The extra space appears to be coming from the label, seen here at the bottom of each `control-group`, which jqueryval creates dynamically. However:

[image: Node Tree]

The label is ghosted out and does not show as taking up any space on the page when you hover over it.

What is making this space appear?

---

*Runtime HTML extracted from dev tools follows - as per screenshot:*

```
<form id="form-account-create" action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-group has-feedback has-success">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Valid Email Address:</label>
                        <small>You will need this to activate your account.</small>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
                            <input type="email" aria-describedby="emailStatus" name="email" id="email" class="form-control valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                        </div>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                        <span class="sr-only" data-error-role="message" id="emailStatus">(success)</span>
                    <label id="email-error" class="error" for="email"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-group has-feedback has-error">
                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" aria-describedby="usernameStatus" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
                        </div>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                        <span class="sr-only" data-error-role="message" id="usernameStatus">(success)</span>
                    <label id="username-error" class="error" for="username">Please enter at least 3 characters.</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" aria-describedby="passwordStatus" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only" data-error-role="message" id="passwordStatus">(success)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="passconf" class="control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" aria-describedby="passconfStatus" name="passconf" id="passconf" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only" data-error-role="message" id="passconfStatus">(success)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

*And the jquery validator:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('#form-account-create');
    form.validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                password: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            passconf: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: password
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: {
                password: "Your password should contain at least one letter and one digit."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var status = $(element).closest('.control-group');
            error.appendTo(status);
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            element = $(element);
            var controlGroup = element.closest('.control-group');
            controlGroup.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            controlGroup.find('.form-control-feedback').html('<i class="fa fa-times"></i>');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element = $(element);
            var controlGroup = element.closest('.control-group');
            controlGroup.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            controlGroup.find('.form-control-feedback').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("password", function (value) {
        return /[a-zA-Z]/.test(value) && /\d/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter and a digit
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT**

It would appear this is some sort of browser bug (Firefox 38.0.5). If I just add a BLANK style attribute onto the status message node in the inspector tools, the gap closes. I've moved it up under it's parent instead and everything now works.

Comment: Without access to inspect your CSS, it's impossible to say.  What do you expect to happen?  What do you prefer to happen?  The jQuery Validate plugin simply inserts the `<label>` element and toggles its classes & visibility.  Without Bootstrap, this `<label>` takes up NO space whatsoever when it is not visible... therefore, you'll need to closely examine the CSS of your layout and Bootstrap in order to answer "why?".

Comment: Side-note:  You really *should* be using the `unhighlight` function to "undo" whatever you're doing with `highlight` function, not `success`.

Comment: The label shows a computed size of 0x0, and doesn't appear on any of the inspector tools to be taking up any space - HOWEVER, the gap left is the exact size it would be, were it not hidden. Nothing else is in the space. When I delete the element with the inspector the gap closes up, but again - it's completely hidden, 0 computed size, doesn't show up in the highlighting, nothing. It's really odd.

Comment: Yes, it's odd, but there's nothing shown in your question that would explain it.  It's certainly not the JavaScript.  You must inspect the CSS of the DOM layout to determine what's really happening... could be anything.

Comment: Hm, yeah - sadly, that's what I'm doing and I see no reason at all why the gap isn't closing up again. I'll try just moving it up to the parent and see if it prefers that (as well as switching to unhighlight - thanks for that)

Comment: Inspect the CSS of the sibling elements for spacing, padding, margin, etc.  You can use your browser's DOM inspection tools to live-edit the CSS to see what makes the space go away.  In Safari, I would uncheck each CSS property one at a time until the layout changes.

Comment: Completely with you - been trying to explain it, but you know when you roll over the siblings, and you can see the brightly coloured boxes denoting main area, padding, margin etc? I'm going over every single one of them and none of them are inside that gap at all - label WOULD be, if it wasn't hidden, but none of the others are. Normally I'd have the culprit of this sort of error rounded up in no time.

Comment: Don't forget about collapsing margins.  Otherwise, could be a margin on a sibling of a parent.  Otherwise, use the DOM inspector to turn off ALL CSS properties and then turn them on one at a time.

Comment: See my update - seems to be some sort of browser bug where it just doesn't pick up that it needs to redo the layout, no idea why. As soon as you touch any property it just snaps back to where I'd been expecting it to. Moving it up to the parent seems to have made the issue go away at least! Thanks for looking at it anyway :)

Comment: Browser bug?  Did you confirm it by also trying it in Safari, Chrome, Explorer, etc?  If you get the same results in all browsers, then it cannot be a bug since every brand of browser is constructed differently.  If the issue is confined only to Firefox 38.0.5, then yeah, might be a bug.

Comment: Changing success to unhighlight fixed it for me. Thanks, Sparky.